# Ajax Get Request with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, cordova

This is my .html page with ajax request

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var a_id;

if (location.search) {
    a_id = location.search.substring(1);
    document.write(a_id);
}


$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: "http://192.168.1.5:8080/SurveyApp3/getSingleAgent?a_id="+a_id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data, status){

        console.log(data);

        },
    error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown){

        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }

});

</script>
```

And this is my Spring MVC controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/getSingleAgent", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSingleAgents(@RequestParam("a_id") long a_id){

    List<Agents> agent= SpringController.getInstance().getSingleAgent(a_id);

    JSONObject json= new JSONObject(agent.get(0));

    System.out.println(json);
    return json.toString();

}
```

The ajax request is called and before that **document.write(a_id)** correctly prints the value. Also, the controller is called successfully, all code in controller method executes the way it has to execute and **System.out.println(json);** also prints required data.

My problem here is with the ajax request. Instead of calling success:function, ajax calls error:function and the following error occurs in the log.

```
08-04 20:39:05.191: D/CordovaLog(32740): [object Object]
08-04 20:39:05.191: I/chromium(32740): [INFO:CONSOLE(36)] "[object Object]", source:   file:///android_asset/www/updateAgentForm.html?9999999999 (36)
08-04 20:39:05.191: D/CordovaLog(32740): error
08-04 20:39:05.191: I/chromium(32740): [INFO:CONSOLE(37)] "error", source: file:///android_asset/www/updateAgentForm.html?9999999999 (37)
08-04 20:39:05.201: D/CordovaLog(32740): Not Found
08-04 20:39:05.201: I/chromium(32740): [INFO:CONSOLE(38)] "Not Found", source: file:///android_asset/www/updateAgentForm.html?9999999999 (38)
```

Where am I going wrong? The problem lies in the ajax is what I believe.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to add `@ResponseBody` over your `getSingleAgents` method.

Comment: Question is nicely asked. Providing logs here had become out of fashion. Upvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem is in Spring MVC when rendering the view (check the logs). Since your method returns String, Spring expects it to be the name of the view to render. 
If you want to return Json, I suggest you return POJO List and annonate method with @ResponseBody as sp00m suggested in comments

Comment: It worked! Also I made one more modification. Changed dataType in ajax to html instead of json. Along with what you said, it works fine. Thank you.